# Javascript like Math.random() in python (17 decimal point precision)

Tags: python

Python `ramdon.random()` gives random number with 15 precision point.
Is there a way to get 17 point just like javasctip `Math.random()`.

I tried this and it works. Any other way?

```
import random
print(format(random.random(), '.17g'))
```

P.S.: I am not from Math background (I'm from biology).

My actual need to mimic JavaScript random as one of the website uses that to dynamically create some validation which I want to do with python to scrape that site.

Comment: This is just differences in the way *floats are printed*

Comment: Plus, Javascript `Math.random()` is often much *worse* than Python `random.random()` - I know on some browsers, it only has 32 bits of randomness, while Python `random.random()` has 53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print your random float with 17 digits after the decimal point like this:

```
import random
print(f'{random.random():.17f}')
```

The internal precision of a Python float is accurate enough for many if not most needs. If you need greater precision you should consider looking into the *decimal* module

Comment: Thanks for understanding the question. My actual need to mimic JavaScript random as one of the website uses that to dynamically create some validation involving javascript `Math.random()`  which I want to do with python to scrape that site.

Answer (score 3):

Both `Math.random()` and `random.random()` return IEEE 754 doubles.

The difference you're seeing is because of the way they're converted to strings. Their length is not constant, see this code for example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  const s = Math.random().toString()
  if (!counter[s.length]) {
    counter[s.length] = 1
  } else {
    counter[s.length]++
  }
}
```

```
{
  "12": 5,
  "13": 47,
  "14": 700,
  "15": 6722,
  "16": 66634,
  "17": 665327,
  "18": 6112214,
  "19": 2813254,
  "20": 302418,
  "21": 29547,
  "22": 2824,
  "23": 281,
  "24": 27
}
```

And for Python:

```py
>>> Counter(len(str(random.random())) for _ in range(10000000))
Counter({
 11: 1,
 12: 8,
 13: 66,
 14: 676,
 15: 6678,
 16: 66628,
 17: 665271,
 18: 6109863,
 19: 2815051,
 20: 302708,
 21: 30569,
 22: 2481
})
```